# Altura dinámica celda API POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo:

```
CellStyle style = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
style.setWrapText(true);

HSSFSheet sheet = document.createSheet("Test");
sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 5000)

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
cell.setCellValue(text);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Si el valor de la celda es más ancho sigue hacia la otra celda, no se si es posible que se ajuste al ancho y se haga la altura dinámica

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [autoSizeColumn](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn(int))

```
for (x = 0; x < sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); x++) {
        results.autoSizeColumn(x);
  }
```

Comment: esto cambia el tamaño de columna, no el alto de fila

Comment: @lois6b efectivamente esta solucion no me vale, por cierto borraste tu anterior respuesta?

Comment: @sirdaiz si, no encontré nada util y puesto que añadiste mi `setWrapText` a tu pregunta explicando que no te sirve, pues la borré